# Why Isn't my If-Then statement working in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I am working on a little program that asks for a username and password in pascal but my if-then statement that checks the username and password isn't working and I'm not sure why...
Here is the code, please let me know what is wrong with my code, thanks!

```
program userpas;
uses
    crt;
var
    un : string;
    pass : string;    
begin { main }
    { only for online GDB }
    clrscr;

    { get username }
    writeln('Please enter your username: ');
    readln(un);

    { get password }
    writeln('Please enter your password: ');
    readln(pass);

    { verify username and password }
    if un := jorden then 
        if pass := js3252006 then 
            writeln ('ACCESS GRANTED');
        else writeln('incorrect username or password');

    readkey;
end { main }
```

Comment: You need to find a tutorial that explains basic syntax, and read it carefully. Your code is littered with syntax and logic errors.

Comment: yeah I know I am 3 weeks new to programing in pascal and still figuring it out.

Comment: Which is why you should find a tutorial and follow it to learn the basics.

Comment: You could also start by explaining what you mean by it "isn't working". You need to be specific. Does it compile? If not, what's the error? And if there's an error, it likely gives you a line number. If so, you should look at that line number, read the error message, and try to figure out what it's saying about that line.

Comment: Yeah I did and it works now but it just wasn't running even tho it would compile but it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the following snippet of your code:

```pascal
if un := jorden then if pass := js3252006 then writeln ('ACCESS GRANTED');
else writeln('incorrect username or password');
```

I see several problems here:

- The `:=` indicates *assignment,* not comparison. If you want to compare, you need to use `=`.
- Unless you have *variables* called `jorden` and `js3252006`, those will need to be quoted strings.
- Semi-colons are statements *separators* in Pascal, not terminators<sup>(a)</sup>. Your use of a semicolon in the "true" section of the `if` is problematic, as it terminates the entire `if` statement, rendering the `else` a syntax error.
- An `else` will bind to only one `if`, meaning what you *actually* have is below (once the other issues are fixed).

```pascal
if un = 'jorden':
    if pass = 'js3252006':
        writeln ('ACCESS GRANTED')
    else:
        writeln('incorrect username or password')
```

Hence you'll see *no* message if you enter a user name other than `jorden`. You would be better off using something akin to:

```pascal
if (un = 'jorden') and (pass = 'js3252006') then
    writeln ('ACCESS GRANTED')
else
    writeln('incorrect username or password')
```

I've left the semicolon off there because it doesn't belong with the statement itself. It would only be need if there was another statement following.

A complete program, should you wish to test it locally (or on [an online Pascal compiler site](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler)), is shown below:

```pascal
program PaxCode;

var un: string = 'jorden';
var pass: string = 'js3252006';

begin
    if (un = 'jorden') and (pass = 'js3252006') then
    begin
        writeln ('ACCESS GRANTED')
    end
    else
    begin
        writeln('incorrect username or password')
    end
end.
```

You can simply adjust the `var` statements to test all the cases you're interested in.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Keep in mind that `;` is a statement *separator* in Pascal, not a statement *terminator.* That means they can royally mess up your logic if used wrongly. I haven't done Pascal since the late 80s but the one thing I remember *most* is the separator/terminator distinction - that was something our lecturers really drilled into us :-)

It's also why, were I return to the Pascal fold, I would *embrace* `begin/end` (as per my final code block above) to ensure there was no chance for the compiler to misunderstand me.

Comment: wait but now with the last part of code you recommended I get this error message:                             Compiling main.pas
main.pas(35,20) Error: Operator is not overloaded: "Constant String" and "ShortString"
main.pas(37,1) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode

Comment: @corruptchimp745: forgot the parentheses, fixed now. Will also add a complete program for testing.

Comment: ok thank you, I added parenthesis thinking that was the problem but it still comes up with a fatal error